# how i make jquery responsive image viewer slider in my jquery mobile application?

Tags: javascript, mobile

I am using light gallery image viewer plugin. But when i click small icon OF IMAGE the image viewer will appear, I want image viewer to be appear on browser when the page loads . Is there any other plugin ?